# Сложный sql запрос из нескольких таблиц для сводной таблицы

Tags: php, sql, mysql

Доброе время всем!

Банальная задача составить запрос (или несколько) из многих таблиц для создания сводной таблицы.

Есть 5 таблиц:

lessons (уроки) с полями: `id|title|date`
evals (оценки) с полями: `id|eval|lesson_id|pupil_id|subject_id|date`
subjects (предметы) с полями: `id|title`
pupils (ученики) с полями: `id|firstname|lastname`
absent (пропуски) с полями: `id|pupil_id|lesson_id`

Составить таблицу в виде страницы школьного журнала:

[image]

N - любое число (то есть кол-во учеников и уроков произвольное).
Задачу решил, используя циклы в php. Работает нормально, пока записей в таблицах мало. Как только оценок наберется пару миллионов, уроков полмиллиона, то виснет страшно. Подскажите способ избежать циклов. Направьте на верное решение. Заранее спасибо!

**Обновление**

Мой вопрос и состоит в том, чтобы узнать как получить все данные сразу. Я пробовал "слепить" все таблицы с помощью join:

```
select
`evals`.`pupil_id` `pupil_id`, 
`evals`.`lesson_id` `lesson_id`, 
`evals`.`eval` `eval`,
`evals`.`id` `eval_id`
from
`evals` `evals`
join
`lessons` `lessons`
on
`evals`.`lesson_id`=`lessons`.`id`
left join
`absent` `absent`
on 
`absent`.`pupil_id`=`evals`.`pupil_id`
where
`evals`.`subject_id`=10 and 
`lessons`.`date` between '1409515200' and '1420920000'
```

Comment: Вы запросы в цикле делаете? Если да, то избавьтесь от них и получайте все данные сразу, то нет, то приведите код вашего решения

Comment: Мой вопрос и состоит в том, чтобы узнать как получить все данные сразу. Я пробовал "слепить" все таблицы с помощью join:
select
`evals`.`pupil_id` `pupil_id`, 
`evals`.`lesson_id` `lesson_id`, 
`evals`.`eval` `eval`,
`evals`.`id` `eval_id`
from
`evals` `evals`
join
`lessons` `lessons`
on
`evals`.`lesson_id`=`lessons`.`id`
left join
`absent` `absent`
on 
`absent`.`pupil_id`=`evals`.`pupil_id`
where
`evals`.`subject_id`=10 and 
`lessons`.`date` between '1409515200' and '1420920000'

Comment: @Agloval, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 2):

Что-нибудь такое попробуйте:

```
select p.lastname, e.date, ifnull(a.lesson_id,e.eval) from pupils p
left join evals e on p.id=e.pupil_id
left join subjects s on e.subject_id=s.id
left join absent a on p.id=a.pupil_id
where s.id=?
```

Было бы удобно, если еще предварительные данные представили в таблицах. После получения ответа запроса есть возможность пихнуть обработку на каком-то ЯП?

Comment: Обрабатываю запросы на пхп. Этот запрос впихнул в phpmyadmin. Сервер повесился. В таблицах строк немного. В absent только 111000, в остальных - не больше 10000.